# How can I clear analysis result for SonarLint in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

How can I clear analysis result for SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ IDEA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on discussion in [sonar-lint mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/9ChXV3rA5Xg) there is no such a feature implemented.

Comment: It is imlemented now :)

Comment: How?? @RuslanLópez

Comment: by cnnecting connect SonarLint to a SonarQube server, which should be possible from version 2.0